# SPARQL hanging when asked about two values

Tags: sparql, wikidata

When I try to query what geographical areas two cities belong Wikidata SparQL query hangs. It works fine for each of the cites.

Any ideas what's going on and whether a workaround is needed?

```
# This works:
# select ?z ?i where {
#   select ?z ?i where {
#     values ?z { wd:Q936768 }
#     ?z wdt:P131+ ?i.
#   }
# }

# This hangs:
select ?z ?i where {
  select ?z ?i where {
    values ?z { wd:Q936768 wd:Q159288 }
    ?z wdt:P131+ ?i.
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a sub-query, is there a reason for it? If you remove it, the query runs fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Very interesting!
I do have a reason for sub-query. I've got this example by simplifying my practical one. And there I use the subquery to make LIMIT work with labeling SERVICE.
E.g. if I write in one level then this hangs:
  select ?z ?i ?iLabel where {
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
    ?z wdt:P131+ ?i.
  } limit 5

Your comment unblocks me, thank you!
It would still be curious to know what's going on here.

Comment: I have no idea why it’s not working with the sub-query. – I think it would be good to edit your question to include something in the outer query so that possible answers don’t just suggest omitting it.

Comment: Try https://w.wiki/66hU